# Where to ask about problems involving submitting an app to the Mac App Store

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am struggling to submit my application made in Unity to the Mac App Store, mainly due to my lack of understanding of certificates, etc.

As I have struggled to find any answers online that address my problems I have turned to Stack Exchange. I was thinking about asking this question on Stack Overflow, but surely it is not really related to programming and therefore inappropriate. Therefore, I would like to ask where the best place would be to ask a question of this sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/) first, but if you can put together a detailed enough question, the Stack Overflow community does seem to accept questions from developers having problems submitting apps to the Mac App Store.

- [Submitting to Mac App Store keeps giving “Invalid Signature” for app's installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35400874/1288)
- [Can't validate and submit an App to the Mac App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12723351/1288)

I agree that it's not programming per se, but it is a technical issue that's fairly unique to programmers, so it should be considered programming related enough.