# Can anyone give me some tips or suggestions for how I might improve this question so that it can be re-opened?

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [External beta testers are getting app builds only assigned to internal testers in TestFlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534100/external-beta-testers-are-getting-app-builds-only-assigned-to-internal-testers-i)

I'd like to better understand how I can add the requested "details or clarity" to the post. I've edited a few times to try to improve it, but I'd appreciate feedback or suggestions from the community.

Comment: That question reads more like a support question for Apple. We probably never have enough info to help resolve your specific case. Nor the means to repro what you're seeing. You paid for that stuff, open a ticket with Apple support.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341142/where-to-ask-about-problems-involving-submitting-an-app-to-the-mac-app-store/341143#341143

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317180/578411

Comment: How the heck are these users finding the question?  Their expertise is a million miles removed from [testflight], they wouldn't begin to know what the question is even about.  I pinged one of them, maybe we'll get some insight.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I 100% understand your comment. It looks like you're saying the question is mistagged but what the right tag would be remains a mystery.  As you're pinging people I assume you consider the question itself on-topic despite the arguments in some of the meta posts I linked earlier? It might be that I should have left the champagne bottle closed for a little longer ...

Comment: @rene cheers, but Hans means the question was closed by users with experience in the HTML, CSS, ASP.NET and Azure tags. He wonders how they ended up reading the question and deciding to close it.

Comment: @CodeCaster The close vote review queue could do that, couldn't it!

Comment: Thank you, everyone! @rene, I agree that this is a difficult question for anyone to truly answer. My initial version of the question was more about sussing out if other people have had issues with testing groups "slipping," since if it was a common issue I would have a better idea of where to focus my efforts. I've reached out to Apple Support and they're looking into it.